# State not being changed

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a react js application and doing some basic stuff, it seems the state is not changing when setting a new value. Here it is the code:

```
pageChange = currentPage => {
    const newState = Immutable.merge(this.state, 
        { 
            page: currentPage
        }, 
        { deep: true });
    this.setState(newState);

    console.log(this.state);    // the page property remains the same
    console.log(newState);      // the page property has the new value, the currentPage

    this.openPreview();
}
```

In the code, the current state is not being set, but newState has the new value. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous, it provides a callback that is invoked once the state was updated successfully:

```
this.setState(newState, () => console.log(this.state));
```

Read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?utm_source=caibaojian.com#setstate).

Comment: If I add the 'await' keyword I get a tslint error saying it is only supposed to use in async functions

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the second argument to setState():

```
pageChange = currentPage => {
  ...
  this.setState(
    newState,
    () => this.openPreview() // This occurs -after- setState has finished
                             // ensuring openPreview() works as you expect
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see the state changes after component life cycle completion. In setState's callback, you can find the new values.

```
pageChange = currentPage => {
    const newState = Immutable.merge(this.state, 
        { 
            page: currentPage
        }, 
        { deep: true });
    this.setState(newState, () => {
       // In set state's callback, you can see the new values.
       console.log(this.state);    // the page property remains the same
       console.log(newState);      // the page property has the new value, the currentPage
    });
    this.openPreview();
}
```